# Why is this ValueError exception used here and not TypeError exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand why ValueError is used here and not TypeError.

If userInput is "a", the code below will print "That's not an int!":

```
try:
    val = int(userInput)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

I think that "a" is the wrong type, and not the wrong value.

In my research, according to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html under ValueError, it states that a ValueError is "Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError."

Does this mean that since "int(...)" sets whatever is within the "(...)" to an int, so this will be the right TYPE regardless, but the value of "a" is incorrect since it is alphabetical and therefore it is the wrong value?

Comment: If you type ```help(int)``` you will get: ```Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments are given.``` This basically means that any number-like string will be converted to ```int```. So you last point is correct because ```a``` is not number-like string, but valid type.

Answer (score 1):

A type error will occur if for example "val" was a list object and you tried to add 3 to it like this

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x += 3
```

Here you are setting variable "val" to be an int so there is no type error here, but you are passing a wrong argument to the int() function so that's Value error

> Does this mean that since "int(...)" sets whatever is within the "(...)" to an int, so this will be the right TYPE regardless, but the value of "a" is incorrect since it is alphabetical and therefore it is the wrong value?

so yes, this is right